# How to say, "Google, index my web site only during specific times?"

Tags: web-crawlers, search-engine-indexing, google-index

Is it possible tell Google to  only index my site between certain hours? 
If it is, how can I manage it?

Comment: I don't think that's possible unfortunately

Comment: I could have sworn I had seen that, turns out it was Bing that lets you do that, so the crawl traffic can avoid your regular peak traffic. :-|

Comment: Simple... you don't. Be grateful that its visits your site when it chooses.

Comment: You mean *crawl* (i.e., when Google’s bots visit your pages) instead of *index* (what Google does with the crawled content), right?

Comment: What is the reason for this?

Comment: Thanks for answers. 
unor, right.
@MrWhite,  our site is being visited many people at any time during day and we run all servers. But during the night we just need two servers and are closing others. We dont want to our site is being crawled while IISs are starting. The starting process dures about 2-3 minutes and Google can reindex at that time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to get Google to index your web site only during certain hours of the day.   If your web site isn't "always on" and "always available", Google doesn't want to index it at all.

I can no longer find a reference to it in the [Google Webmaster Guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769?hl=en), but Google used to specifically state that your site had to be always available.   They gave an example of a site hosted on a server at your workplace that was only turned on during business hours.   The guidelines said that Google wouldn't index such a site.

At the very least you should make the information on your website available all the time.   If you need to shut down some functionality at certain times of the day you may do so and put a message up to users explaining why.   I've seen that before with Jewish owned eCommerce sites.  You can't order anything from them one day a week on their holy day.

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't tell Google when to crawl your site. What you can do is [limit the crawl rate](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/48620?hl=en) in order to avoid bandwidth problems on your server.

> If Google is making too many requests per second to your site and slowing down your server, you can limit the crawl rate for root-level sites—for example, www.example.com and http://subdomain.example.com. The crawl rate that you set is the maximum crawl rate that Googlebot should make. Note that it does not guarantee that Googlebot will reach this maximum rate.

You can set the crawl rate at Google Seach Console (site settings).

[image]